# SwiftUI: ViewModifier isn't in sync with its backed view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a simple SwiftUI view that has a `StateObject`, I have created a `ViewModifier` for that view and added an `onReceive` event inside the view modifier to listen for changes from the main view (`MyView`) as follows:

```
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var myProperty: Bool = false
}

struct MyView: View {
    @StateObject var myViewModel = MyViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
            .modifier(MyViewModifier(myViewModel: myViewModel))
            .onTapGesture {
                myViewModel.myProperty = true
            }
    }
}

struct MyViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    @ObservedObject var myViewModel: MyViewModel
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onReceive(myViewModel.$myProperty, perform: { newValue in
                print("new value for myProperty is \(newValue)")
            })
    }
}
```

However, when I tap on the text "Hello world", the `onReceive` modifier isn't triggered in `MyViewModifier`, what I have tried is:

1. Changing the `StateObject` to `ObservedObject` in `MyView`.
2. Changing the `ObservedObject` to `StateObject` in `MyViewModifier`.
3. Changing the `ObservedObject` to `Binding` in `MyViewModifier` but couldn't find a way to pass a binding for the whole `StateObject` from `MyView` to `MyViewModifier`.

none of the above solved the issue.

`- note:` I need to pass the whole view model object down to `MyViewModifier` because this is a small sample from a large project which needs the whole view model object to be available in the view modifier.

Comment: If this is a duplicate of your own post then why did you post this question in the first place?

Comment: @pawello2222 I posted it by mistake, I guess I have to delete it

Comment: I don’t think you can - there is an upvoted answer. But please accept the pending duplicate vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `onChange(of:perform:)`

> Adds a modifier for this view that fires an action when a specific value changes.
> [https://developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onreceive(_:perform:))

```
onChange(of: myViewModel.myProperty) { value in
    print("Value \(value)")
}
```